# Using Pandas Series of dates(strings) as x ticks on a plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have 3 csv's with stock data, all from 2012-01-1 to 2017-01-01. I have used Pandas to make Dataframes out of them, and am instructed to turn them into this example plot:
[Desired outcome][1]

My only issue is that Pandas isn't taking the 'Date' Series from my Dataframe to create the X axis of time like in the picture, instead I get an X axis of values 0-1400 [My failed plot][2] (I have 1258 dates, so it's getting the index of the date rather than the date itself).

This is my code for the plot right now:

```
ford['Open'].plot()
tesla['Open'].plot()
GM['Open'].plot(x=ford['Date'],figsize=(16,8),title='Open price',xlabel='Date')
plt.legend(['Ford','Tesla','GM'])
```

I have tried using the xticks argument and passing it tesla['Date'] (The name of the date series), but when I do I get this error:

> ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: 0       2012-01-03
> 1       2012-01-04
> 2       2012-01-05
> 3       2012-01-06
> 4       2012-01-09
> ...
> 1253    2016-12-23
> 1254    2016-12-27
> 1255    2016-12-28
> 1256    2016-12-29
> 1257    2016-12-30
> Name: Date, Length: 1258, dtype: object

I couldn't find this particular issue on google and I've looked for an hour. I'm definitely missing something but I don't know what. Thanks for any help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz8GU.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSihy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the index of the dates you want to display (say, one tick every 200 value), and use plt.xticks. Try this:

```
import numpy as np

ford['Open'].plot()
tesla['Open'].plot()
GM['Open'].plot()
plt.legend(['Ford','Tesla','GM'])
ticks = np.arange(0, len(ford['Date']), 200)
plt.xticks(ticks, ford['Date'][ticks])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! But I'm not sure why. What does the last [ticks] do to ford['Date']?

Comment: You're welcome.
`ford['Date']` is an array of all dates, and `ticks` contains the indexes of the dates you wish to keep for the plot labelling. So `ford['Date'][ticks]` returns an array with only the dates that will be displayed. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks a lot I was really struggling with that one

Answer (score 1):

With pandas plots, you can create a graph by stacking each of them without specifying the x-axis. The data was obtained from Yahoo Finance in one-month units.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ford['Open'].plot()
tesla['Open'].plot()
GM['Open'].plot(figsize=(16,8),title='Open price',xlabel='Date')
plt.legend(['Ford','Tesla','GM'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer for this particular problem (with pandas). See my answer below for more general pyplot labelling, especially if you want more control over your labels.